# Cannot connect to mysql database in Excel 2016 VBA

Tags: mysql, excel, database, vba, excel-2016

I'm trying to write a straightforward piece of code to connect to a MySQL database.

```
Sub DBConnection()
Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim connectionStr As String
connectionStr = "DRIVER={SQL SERVER} ;SERVER=localhost; database=sakila; uid=test1; pwd=123"
conn.Open connectionStr
conn.Close
MsgBox "Connected!"
End Sub
```

I am faced with this error when I run it:

[image: Error]

I suspect the details I am providing in the connection may be incorrect but I'm not sure.

**User and database name in the MySQL workbench:**
[image: img]

Perhaps it's the server name but *as I understand* it being on my local machine it should be **localhost**.

Would appreciate any help on this, thanks!

I have the following MYSQL products installed

[image]

I have installed the 5.2 driver and followed the connection string for 5.2 from the website provided. The error is still persisting (see below). I'll keep googling but any help would be appreciated as I am very new to this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My first stop for connection strings is [**connectionstrings.com**](https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/), where you should e able to find a connection string that fits your MySQL version and your connection method.

---

The *standard* MySQL connection string is:

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;
```

...and several others on the [site](https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/) for various situations.

Comment: Thanks, I have installed ODBC 5.2 and followed the connection string from the website you suggested. I am still seeing the error. Please see my edits.